# ARPACK- Reverse Communication Interface

Tags: fortran, arpack

I am trying to use ARPACK to diagonalize a sparse Hermitian matrix.

My program is executing without error but returning incorrect eigenvalues.  I have tried to trace the problem back.

The work is done by two functions:

`znaupd` and a function I have defined `av` to perform matrix vector multiplication.

`znaupd` takes a vector as input and passes a resultant vector to `av`.  There is some starting default vector that ARPACK chooses.

Looking at the output of my program, it seems like the default vector is essentially being chosen to be the zero vector, and `znaupd` just passes this same zero vector to `av` every time.

Comment: Just so you know, you can pass your own initial vector by passing info $\neq 0$ to znaupd.  I don't think this has to do with your problem, though.  What are the values of info and ido throughout the iterations?

Comment: Maybe you can show us the part of your program that calls ARPACK functions, so that we could take a look and tell you if we see something.